# React prop not working on child component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

So I have my parent component with some data:

```
  const [purchaseData, setpurchaseData] = useState({
    tickets: 0,
    email: "",
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "",
   });
```

and 2 child components:

```
 <PurchaseForm purchaseData={purchaseData} />
 <FinalPreview purchaseData={purchaseData} />
```

but idk why the  doesn't take the data. The 1st child component is working perfectly with the purchaseData, but when I try to open the  it's just a blank page and doesn't read the data(returns undefined).

Comment: Add the code for child components as well

Comment: Parent component:  https://pastebin.com/cqnrjRNn                                                                PurchaseForm:  https://pastebin.com/RFsxAH5h                                                                           FinalPreview not working component:   https://pastebin.com/yZpgBu05

Comment: Inside FinalForm and PurchaseForm, on your PurchaseLayout component, you're passing children prop. Why?

Comment: because the PurchaseLayout  is just a wrapper:                                 ***export default function PurchaseLayout({ children }) {
  return <div className="form__container">{children}</div>;
}***      and I read somewhere that you should place the "children" prop as well

Comment: You don't need to separately pass children prop on component. It is available by default. 
`<PurchaseLayout>...code </PurchaseLayout>` and this is correct `export default function PurchaseLayout({ children })`

Comment: For more info on children prop, you can take a look at these [Docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/composition-vs-inheritance.html)